# Whats the best approach to upload images in queue

Tags: java, android

I am into and android app which has a camera capture option on screen user can go on clicking pictures and as sooon as picture is clicked it needs to be uploaded, user still stays in camera hitting capture button as many times as he likes.I m informing user about status in notification area.

I need to know a way of implementing this upload task in failsafe way. I m confused should i use service or a thread or multiple treads.

Please suggest the idea to implement the upload stuff.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use an [Async Task](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). You can perform net operations in another thread safely. Thats the approach I would take, I can add some example code for you if needed.

Comment: Buf afaik Asynctasks are suitable for short operations

Comment: No, Async tasks are for anytime when a task of an unknown length needs to take place. Async task executes it another thread that is not the UI thread to avoid UI lag.